# How to identify columns in a data frame that has same value?

Tags: r, duplicates

I have a data frame

```
         A B C D E F
         1 2 3 3 4 1
         2 3 5 5 8 2
         6 4 9 9 0 6
         1 2 3 3 8 1
```

I want the names of columns that holds identical values.

Preferred output : A,F,C,D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expanding @Ronak Shah's solution to produce OPs preferred output:

```
df <- data.frame(A = c(1,2,6,1), B = c(2,3,4,2), C = c(3,5,9,3), D = c(3,5,9,3), E = c(4,8,0,8), F = c(1,2,6,1))
df <- df[, duplicated(t(df)) | duplicated(t(df), fromLast = TRUE)]
df <- df[order(df[1])]
names(df)
[1] "A" "F" "C" "D"
```

Note that `order()` is used so rearrange `df` so that `names(df)` returns the preferred output.

Answer (score 1):

`duplicated` works on each row of data frame. We could transpose it to make it work for each column and subset the names of the columns.

```
names(df)[duplicated(t(df)) | duplicated(t(df), fromLast = TRUE)]
#[1] "A" "C" "D" "F"
```

Comment: Our solution are essentially the same, but I think `as.list()` (which should only change the class attribute)  should be faster than `t()`?

Comment: Not sure If OP requires to know which is duplicated with which. i.e. A -> F and C -> D

Comment: @sindri_baldur Not sure if it is faster but one thing to note is `t()` converts it into a matrix.

Answer (score 1):

You could convert the `data.frame` to a `list` and use `duplicated()`:

```
names(df)[duplicated(as.list(df)) | duplicated(as.list(df), fromLast = TRUE)]
# [1] "A" "C" "D" "F"
```

You could also `duplicated.default()` directly on the  `data.frame`:

```
names(df)[duplicated.default(df) | duplicated.default(df, fromLast = TRUE)]
# [1] "A" "C" "D" "F"
```

**Data**:

```
df <- data.frame(
  A = c(1L, 2L, 6L, 1L), B = c(2L, 3L, 4L, 2L), C = c(3L, 5L, 9L, 3L),
  D = c(3L, 5L, 9L, 3L), E = c(4L, 8L, 0L, 8L), F = c(1L, 2L, 6L, 1L)
)
```

**Benchmark**:

Converting a `data.frame` to a list (`as.list()`) is much more efficient than transposing and converting to a matrix (`t()`):

```
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(as.list(df), t(df))
Unit: microseconds
        expr    min      lq     mean median      uq     max neval cld
 as.list(df)  2.677  2.9010  3.84244  3.570  3.5700  28.114   100  a 
       t(df) 69.615 71.1765 77.11636 72.293 75.6395 219.554   100   b
```