# Finding rows where a value is duplicated in select columns using R

Tags: duplicates, row, data-cleaning

Long-time stack overflow lurker, but now decided to test the waters to see if someone here could help me with a data-cleaning issue that has bugged me for quite a while. I have data that has recorded the order in which subjects (noted by 'id' in the data set) noticed certain stimuli, where columns represent the individual stimuli and values 1-4 the order in which the stimuli were noticed. Zeroes denote stimuli that were not noticed and I am not interested in rows with multiple zeroes, so they can be recoded as NA too. Here is an example dataset of what it could look like:

```
df <- data.frame(id=c('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'),
                 stim1=c(1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1),
                 stim2=c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2),
                 stim3=c(0, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2),
                 stim4=c(0, 3, 4, 0, 0, 4))

df
  id stim1 stim2 stim3 stim4
1  A     1     2     0     0
2  B     0     2     1     3
3  C     1     2     2     4
4  D     1     2     3     0
5  E     0     2     1     0
6  F     1     2     2     4
```

Now, as you can see, subjects C and F have the value 2 on two different stimuli. What I am trying to do is find all rows where duplicates of any value 1 to 4 across columns stim1 to stim4 exist. The goal is to find the IDs and stimuli where such problematic data exist so I can verify from the respective subjects' raw data whether it was simply a typo in data entry (e.g., one of the 2's should be a 3) and correct it before moving on to do other things with the data.

I guess there is some elegant dplyr solution to this (rowwise something?), but even with a fair bit of googling I could not find anything that would fit this exact issue.

An ideal solution would print me the ID and the values which are duplicated, something like this in the example dataframe:

```
C 2
F 2
```

But even getting the IDs where duplicated values are present would be helpful as the data set is not overly large to go through the duplicates by hand if such filtering was applied.

Many potential solutions left me hanging by offering something that fits for finding completely duplicated rows (which is not the issue). I also tried transposing the dataframe and then using generic duplicate functions but did not manage to do something quite appropriate.

Here is, I think, a similar query, the solution of which I tried:

[How to identify columns in a data frame that has same value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54781208/how-to-identify-columns-in-a-data-frame-that-has-same-value?rq=3)

```
df <- data.frame(id=c('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'),
                 stim1=c(1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1),
                 stim2=c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2),
                 stim3=c(0, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2),
                 stim4=c(0, 3, 4, 0, 0, 4))

df

  id stim1 stim2 stim3 stim4
1  A     1     2     0     0
2  B     0     2     1     3
3  C     1     2     2     4
4  D     1     2     3     0
5  E     0     2     1     0
6  F     1     2     2     4

df <- df[, duplicated(t(df)) | duplicated(t(df), fromLast = TRUE)]
df <- df[order(df[1])]
Error in `[.data.frame`(df, 1) : undefined columns selected
```

This is just one of many solutions that I've tried that returns an error or gives me an empty object as a result, so there must be something I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a concatenated vector like:

```
x <- apply(df[,2:ncol(df)], 1, function(x) paste0(x, collapse=""))
```

Followed by:

```
y <- duplicated(x, fromLast=T) | duplicated(x)
```

This will assure match from first to last occurrence of any duplicated value.

Finally properly find indices with:

```
df[y,]
```

**OUPUT:**

```
  id stim1 stim2 stim3 stim4
3  C     1     2     2     4
6  F     1     2     2     4
```